# find all values 'x' that do not contain a 'y'

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to provide a list of all active `site`s that do not contain have a `domain`

```
SELECT companies.name,sites.name,sites.association 
FROM companies JOIN sites ON sites.company = companies.id 
JOIN domains ON domains.site != sites.id WHERE sites.is_deleted = 0 
AND domains.is_primary = 1 AND domains.is_deleted = 0
```

I am joining on the condition that the primary key for `sites` does not correspond with anything in the `domains.site` field. However, I know I am not getting the output I need since I know the number or rows I want and I am generating more than that.

The uml diagram for te schema I am working with is [here](http://s31.postimg.org/is0actvtn/Screen_Shot_2016_04_19_at_4_48_24_PM.png) (it's a little funky).

Comment: See [this great explanation of joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Comment: No pictures, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this might give you what you need assuming you're trying to find sites that do not have a primary domain.  it uses left join and checks to see if the domain record is null/missing

```
SELECT  companies.name,
        sites.name,
        sites.association
FROM    companies
        JOIN sites ON sites.company = companies.id
        LEFT JOIN domains ON domains.site = sites.id
                             AND domains.is_primary = 1
                             AND domains.is_deleted = 0
WHERE   sites.is_deleted = 0
        AND domains.id IS NULL
```

You can also consider using NOT EXISTS

```
SELECT  companies.name,
        sites.name,
        sites.association
FROM    companies
        JOIN sites ON sites.company = companies.id
WHERE   sites.is_deleted = 0
        AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM    domains d
            WHERE   d.site = sites.id
                    AND d.is_primary = 1
                    AND d.is_deleted = 0
        )
```

here is a sql fiddle for you to test [**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c4e5c7/1)

Comment: the `domains.id` field does not contain any null values, which is part of why this query is driving me crazy